# Redefine moderncv header, headheight

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, moderncv

I am writing a curriculum vitae at the moment using the `moderncv` package for this. However, I would like to use the header on every single page. While on the first page, I want to use the option to print a photo as well (commented out at the moment) and therefore, using `\makecvtitle`, I want the header to be printed without the photo on the following pages. To do so, I closed the first page with `\clearpage` and refined the header by using `fancyhdr` and the commands taken from the `moderncvheadi.sty` file. The only thing I am failing to reproduce is the right height of the header. Actually I don't quite understand how it is defined in the `moderncvheadi.sty` and how I have to include it in my header definition. Can someone help me out?

**EDIT**

I know, I can call e.g. `\makecvhead`. But if there is more than one page following, I need to make every pagebreak and `\makecvhead` manually. When printing a list of publication from an `.bib file` this is not possible for example. To clarify it, I want to print the header on every page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, sans, details]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
%
\title{Dr. of blub}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Awesome street 00}{01234 Kleingibtsnicht}{}
\mobile{0815-4711}
\phone{0815-4712}
\email{me@there.com}
%\photo[64pt]{JMP_photo.jpg}
\extrainfo{* 01.02.1899 in Somewhere}
%
\begin{document}
%
\makecvtitle
%
\section{job experience}
%
  \cventry{1900 -- 2000}{I was}{here}{and}{did}{something}
%
\section{Some knowledge I got}
%
\closesection
%
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% redefine header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\lhead{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}
        }%
%
\rhead{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
            }
\makeatother
%
\section{some more great knowledge}
%
\closesection
%
\end{document}
```

**Output**

**First page**
[image]
**Second page**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you missed in your code for the second and the following pages is to define the length of your used header like:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{70pt}
```

With this command the header gets 70 pt height (change it to what you need) for your personal informations, and this works with your bib file too.  You gave no bibliography so please try it with your own code ...

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, sans, details]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
%
\title{Dr. of blub}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Awesome street 00}{01234 Kleingibtsnicht}{}
\mobile{0815-4711}
\phone{0815-4712}
\email{me@there.com}
\photo[64pt]{JMP_photo.jpg}
\extrainfo{* 01.02.1899 in Somewhere}
%

\begin{document}
%
\makecvtitle
%
\section{job experience}
%
  \cventry{1900 -- 2000}{I was}{here}{and}{did}{something}
%
\section{Some knowledge I got}
%
\closesection
%
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% redefine header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\lhead{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}
        }%
%
\rhead{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
            }
\makeatother
\setlength{\headheight}{70pt} % <=======================================
%
\section{some more great knowledge}
%
\closesection
%
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting second page (please see that I uncommented your command `\photo`):

[image: resulting second page]

Comment: This already goes in the right direction. However, I wonder what you would need to do, to get the exact same layout as when using `\makecvhead`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you redefined the whole command since you are able to make the header before every page using the command `\makecvhead`, I only undefined the `\photo` command after the first header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, sans, details]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
%
\title{Dr. of blub}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Awesome street 00}{01234 Kleingibtsnicht}{}
\mobile{0815-4711}
\phone{0815-4712}
\email{me@there.com}
\photo[64pt]{example-image}
\extrainfo{* 01.02.1899 in Somewhere}
%
\begin{document}
%
\makecvtitle
%
\section{job experience}
%
  \cventry{1900 -- 2000}{I was}{here}{and}{did}{something}
%
\section{Some knowledge I got}
%
\closesection
%
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% redefine header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\@photo\undefined
\makecvhead
\section{some more great knowledge}
%
\closesection
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If there is more than one page following, I need to make every pagebreak and `\makecvhead` manually. When printing a list of publication from an `.bib file` this is not possible for example.

Comment: you want to add it in all bib related pages too?

Comment: I want to add it on every single page to have a consistent look.